# How to add dictionary to PyEnchant?

Tags: python, spell-checking, pyenchant

I got [PyEnchant](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyenchant/) with files for many languages: `en_US, en_AU, de_DE, fr_FR`. Now I call list of dictionaries and see only small set: `'en', 'en_US', 'en_GB', 'en_CA'`.
I call:

```
items = enchant._broker.list_languages()
```

How to load into Enchant other langs? New files? So `enchant.Dict()` can take it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can check that you have a language  available, from a Python prompt type:

```
import enchant
print enchant.list_languages()
```

Then you need to import it, lets assume german is the one I am looking for. Then, from terminal I type:

```
sudo apt-get install myspell-de-de
```

To check it works, from a Python prompt type:

```
import enchant
d = enchant.Dict('de_DE')
d.check("Hello") # False
d.check("Guten") # True
```

For a fuller list of dictionaries see:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/myspell-dictionary

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/aspell-dictionary

http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/precise/openoffice.org-dictionaries

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ispell-dictionary

Comment: I need to copy to `~/.enchant/myspell`. It is helpful.